# WPF Focused Visual State kicks in only when button pressed, why?

Tags: wpf, visualstates

With respect to the code below, can anyone tell me why when a button is in normal state as well as in focused state, the button does not bounce?  In other words, shouldn't a button bounce anytime it gets focused state, regardless whether it is pressed or not ?

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonTemplateUsingVSM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="249" Width="619">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="outerCircle"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                            To="Orange" Duration="0:0:.4"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To=".9" Duration="0"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" To=".9" Duration="0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="outerCircle"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                            To="Gray" Duration="0:0:.4"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                                                             To="-20" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:.4">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <QuadraticEase/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                                      Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.Color}"/>
                                        <GradientStop x:Name="highlightGradientStop" Offset="1" Color="Red"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".8" ScaleY=".8"/>
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Viewbox>
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </Viewbox>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Height="200" Width="200" FontSize="20" Padding="20" Margin="5">OK</Button>
        <Button Height="200" Width="200" FontSize="20" Padding="20" Margin="5">OK</Button>
        <Button Height="200" Width="200" FontSize="20" Padding="20" Margin="5">OK</Button>
        <Button Height="200" Width="200" FontSize="20" IsEnabled="False" Padding="20" Margin="5">OK</Button>
        <Button Height="200" Width="200" FontSize="20" Padding="20" Margin="5">OK</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

namespace ButtonTemplateUsingVSM
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, a button gets focus only when it's pressed (unless you change it in code).  You can also obtain a keyboard focus.  Therefore, your bouncing animation will only work when one of those buttons is pressed, due to it being set only for the `Focused` state:

```
<VisualStateGroup Name="FocusStates">
    <VisualState Name="Unfocused"/>  <!--Right here-->
    <VisualState Name="Focused">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                             To="-20" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                             Duration="0:0:.4">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <QuadraticEase/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

As you can see, `Unfocused` `VisualState` does not have any animation pertaining to it.  So, unless one of those buttons gets the focus, it won't bounce.  It'll simply change colors from red to orange per the `MouseOver` `VisualState`.

I think this would be a good read for your:  [MSDN Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Explanation for discussion in the comments.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Focus.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Button 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Margin="20" GotFocus="Button1_GotFocus"/>
        <Button Content="Button 2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="75" GotFocus="Button2_GotFocus"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Focus
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button 1 Focused");
        }

        private void Button2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button 2 Focused");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was under the same impression that this is the case -- that is, that a button is in focised state only when it's pressed.  But this example is taken from the book "WPF 4 unleashed", and with respect to that example, there is an illustration which exhausts all of the possibilities (e.g., MouseOver Unfocused, Disabled, Unfocused).  One of those possibilities is "Normal Focused", which is WHY I posted this question ..in that case, I am not sure why "Normal Focused" is mentioned as one possible combination that could result by user interaction ?

Comment: @WITL I'm not aware of Normal Focused state.  There are two state groups for a button.  CommonStates: Normal, MouseOver, Pressed, Disabled  and FocuStates: Unfocused, Focused.  The book might have a typo... many books do.  I don't have the book, so I don't know what it says exactly, but what I told you is how it is.  Here's a good resource for states: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeetenk/archive/2009/07/10/hey-wpf-button-where-are-your-states.aspx

Comment: When you press and release a button ,the button is at CommonStates- Normal and FocuStates- focused , this can be a "Normal Focused" state and the button will still be bouncing

Comment: @WITL Umm... As far as I know, there is no free version of that book.  Remove that link before you get yourself in trouble.  However, read what it says on the bottom of page 645.  It describes in detail what I told you.  So, what happens when you MouseOver?  It goes from Normal State to MouseOver state.  What happens if you press the button?  It goes from Unfocused State to Focused State.  What happens when you move the mouse away from the pressed button?  It goes from MouseOver state to Normal state, but because there is no transition for the animation, the button will continue bouncing.

Comment: @WITL Therefore, the button bounces only when it has received focus.  You are asking why it doesn't bounce in Normal Focused state, but it does.  I think you're confused about what Focus is.  Read the link I've provided in my answer that tells you about Focus in WPF.  There are many ways a Focus can be received, but it's not received, by default, from being moused-over.

Comment: When it goes from Normal State to Mouseover State I understand that the Mouseover animation kicks in but the very user interaction of hovering over the button means, as the following link indicates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745088(v=vs.85).aspx, that " A focused state occurs [when a user moves a mouse pointer over the button]" .  So per my understanding -- and this is where I would appreciate elaboration where I go wrong -- I would expect the Focused animation (i.e., bouncing) to occur at the same time or after the MouseOver state occurs.

Comment: The MouseOver State causes the button to change color, so visually I would expect to see a bouncing button with the yellowish changed color.  Obviously this is not the case – when the mouse is over a button, only the color changes.      I guess your correct statement above that “By default, a button gets focus only when it's pressed (unless you change it in code). You can also obtain a keyboard focus” does not agree with the statement that “A focused state occurs when a user moves a mouse pointer over the button” (from the link I included).  How can I reconcile them?

Comment: @WITL Run the program in the edit of my answer.  By default, button does not receive a focus when it is moused over.  On that MSDN page you've provided they're using wrong labeling and they're confusing you.  If you scroll down a bit and see their code, it shows clearly that they differentiate between MouseOver and Pressed states.  Focus is not received until the button is pressed in that scenario, and the same thing goes for your code.... and the code I've provided.

Comment: @WITL So, to conclude this lengthy conversation.  That documentation is not put together properly.  They're mixing visual states with focus states and are causing you confusion.  Note how 4.5 version of that documentation only shows visual state, without the text (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752065(v=vs.110).aspx).  Unless you change the default behavior, mousing over does not give button a focus.  Period.

Comment: Much appreciation for your B.K help, knowledge, and for being so patient!

Comment: @WITL By the way, if I have answered your question, don't forget to mark an answer.